# Use AutoMapper to map two VM to one Entity object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, automapper, viewmodel

I'm using AutoMapper to map a lot of Entity models to View Model that I use in my controllers and views (.Net MVC)
There is a lot of relations in the DB and so our VM have a lot of childs (who have childs, and so and so)

```
public class InvoiceVMFull : VMBase
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public InvoiceType InvoiceType { get; set; }

    public string Reference { get; set; }

    //.... shortened code for readability
    // list all entity fields

    public List<string> InvoiceMainAddress { get; set; }

    public List<string> InvoiceDlvAddress { get; set; }
}
```

It works just fine, but is very slow and always load from the DB all relations whereas I usually need only a few datas...

So I created some light VM that I want to use for the majority of our pages.

```
public class InvoiceVMLite : VMBase
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Reference { get; set; }

    //.... shortened code for readability
    // list only some of the entity fields (most used)

    public StoredFileVM InvoiceFile { get; set; }
}
```

The problem is I can't find how :

- to map one Entity object to the two VMs and how to choose the right one (to load from DB) using the context (the page or event called)
- to map two VMs to one entity and save (on the DB) only the fields that are present in the VM used and don't erase the absent ones

I tried to create the mapping both VM :

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Invoice, InvoiceVMLite>();
Mapper.CreateMap<Invoice, InvoiceVMFull>();
```

But when I try to call the mapping for Lite, it doesn't exist (have been overridden by Full) :

```
Mapper.Map(invoice, InvoiceEntity, InvoiceVMLite)
```

Answer (score 0):

### Correct Use of Map function

It looks like you are calling map incorrectly.  Try these instead

```
var vmLite = Mapper.Map<Invoice, InvoiceVMLite>(invoice);
var vmFull = Mapper.Map<Invoice, InvoiceVMFull>(invoice);
```

`var vmLite = Mapper.Map(invoice);` `// would work if it were not ambiguous what the destination was based on the input.`

### Entity to two view models

You would usually create two mappings, one for each view model from the one entity.  I'd suggest the cleanest is to have two separate views (separate Actions in a controller) for each view model.  This may involve a quick redirect after you've decided on context which one to use.

### View models to entity

Automapper is not meant for mapping from view models to Entities for many reasons, including the challenge you'd face.  Instead you would pass specific parameters.  The author of Automapper, Jimmy Bogard, wrote a [good article](https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2009/09/18/the-case-for-two-way-mapping-in-automapper/) on why this is the case.

Comment: E->VM : I tried to create maps for both VM with the same destination, but when I call Mapper.Map I get an error : missing map config.
I think the second mapping override the first one.
Can I call createMap in an Action without perf or security problems?
Can I call it several times for the same types or do I have to check if its already mapped?

VM->E : So I have no choice but do it all myself? Find the good entity for the VM, set all linked fields one by one, modify the entity object and then send it to the DB to save it?
If so, I think it would be easier to totally ditch AutoMapper.

Comment: E>VM would have different destinations, one each for each vm.  sounds like you might have the order the wrong way around

Comment: VM->E take a full read of that article.  It's good to be specific about what you're saving.  I find automapper does help as your models grow and you'll probably appreciate this point as your viewmodels vary even more.  That said, if you don't get or buy into the idea behind it maybe it is not for you.

Comment: For E-> VM, I tried to create the mapping both VM :
Mapper.CreateMap<Invoice, InvoiceVMLite>();
Mapper.CreateMap<Invoice, InvoiceVMFull>();

But when I try to call the mapping for Lite, it doesn't exist (have been overridden by Full) :
Mapper.Map(invoice, InvoiceEntity, InvoiceVMLite)

Comment: will update the answer now, just seen what you're doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

I couldnt manage to do that with AutoMapper, and so I created my own convert methods (Entity <=> VM) with a lot of reflexivity, and with specific cases handled in each of the VM classes.

Now I can easily get a full or lite VM from an Entity, and also specify the depth in relation I want to go. So it's A LOT faster and more adaptable than AutoMapper

And I can save a VM to an entity (only saving modified fields if I want) that I create or that i got from base. So it's A LOT faster and adaptable than AutoMapper

In conclusion : Don't use autoMapper, it seem easy but create so many performance issues that it isn't worth it